# using data uploaded via Class FileUpload

Tags: file-upload, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Perhaps a basic question but I can't seem to find a referance in the documentation.

I have a spreadsheet and a UI form containing a FileUpload and Submit widgets.

```
function displayFileDialog() {

  var fileDialog = UiApp.createApplication()
  .setTitle("Select PROJECT XML File")
  .setHeight(100)
  .setWidth(200);
  var form = fileDialog.createFormPanel();
  var flow = fileDialog.createFlowPanel();
  var file = fileDialog.createFileUpload().setName("fileUL");      
  var button = fileDialog.createSubmitButton('submit'); 
  var textedit = fileDialog.createTextBox().setName("textBox");


  flow.add(file);      // add file to flo                                  
  flow.add(textedit);  // testing textedit
  flow.add(button);    // add button to flow                                 
  form.add(flow);      // add flow to form
  fileDialog.add(form);// add form to application

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(fileDialog);  // Display dialog in spreadsheet.
}
```

Running this function displays the UI in the sheet as expected.

When the submit button is pressed this `doPost` function is run:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("doPost - fileUL is-" + e.parameter.fileUL + "-");
  Logger.log("doPost - textEdit is-" + e.parameter.textBox + "-");
}
```

Now if I load a small XML file into the FileUploader and type the test `TESTING` into the textEdit I get the following in the Log window:

```
doPost - fileUL is-FileUpload-
doPost - textEdit is-TESTING-
```

regardless of what the file is it always says `FileUpload`. I'm guessing I'm missing something since the textEdit works, however I can't debug and upload at the same time I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. and the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload?hl=en) don't seem to have any further information.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line of the documentation you provided:

> The result of a FileUpload is a "Blob"

You can read the content of a [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_blob) by using

```
e.parameter.fileUL.getDataAsString();
```

Comment: Perfect... yeah I knew it was a BLOB but I didn't know to look in the base class. Thanks!!